# What does 'leg time' mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

When talking about deliveries or any other standard arrival or departure terminology I often hear the following, which have an obvious meaning.

ETA: Estimated Time of Arrival

ETD: Estimated Time of Departure

But what does `leg time` mean? If it helps, the word was used in a courier company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @Dan Bron's helpful comment:

> A trip can be thought of being composed of several independent parts,
>   delimited by a stop or station or discrete activity (eg a drop-off or
>   pick up). These components are known as “legs”. The elapsed time
>   between the start of a given leg and the completion of that same leg
>   is the “leg time”. They’re called legs because of you draw the whole
>   trip / route on a map, the components will be straight lines, and
>   usually at an angle to each other, like drawing a leg on a stick-man
>   which is bent at the knee.

Leg time can also be thought of as  the difference between the Estimated Time of Arrival and the Estimated Time of Departure or the difference between the Actual Time of Arrival and the Actual Time of Departure, depending on the organization and form being considered.